# templated friend function lookup

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, friend

The following simple code compiles fine

```
class A {
  int x[3];
public:
  A() { x[0]=1; x[1]=2; x[2]=3; }
  friend int const&at(A const&a, unsigned i) noexcept
  {
    return a.x[i];
  }
  friend int foo(A const&a, unsigned i) noexcept
  {
    int tmp = at(a,i);
    return tmp*tmp;
  }
};
```

but if the friends are made templates

```
class A {
  int x[3];
public:
  A() { x[0]=1; x[1]=2; x[2]=3; }

  template<unsigned I>
  friend int const&at(A const&a) noexcept
  {
    static_assert(I<3,"array boundary exceeded");
    return a.x[I];
  }

  template<unsigned I>
  friend int foo(A const&a) noexcept
  {
    int tmp = at<I>(a);   // <- error: use of undeclared identifier 'at'
    return tmp*tmp;
  }
};
```

the look-up rules change and clang complains with said error, but gcc and icpc don't. Who is right (C++11)? and how to get the code fixed for clang?

Comment: Is there a reason you declare the functions as `friend`?

Comment: Try `::at<I>(a)`, but you shouldn't have to.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course (the code here is only a simple example, where no such reason may exist), that's the point of the question.

Comment: `at` needs a declaration in the surrounding namespace. Friend functions without one can only be found via ADL, and that doesn't happen yet when you explicitly specify template arguments, IIRC.

Comment: @Dave no, doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to separate declaration and definition:

```
class A {
  int x[3];
public:
  A() { x[0]=1; x[1]=2; x[2]=3; }

  template<unsigned I>
  friend int const&at(A const&a) noexcept;

  template<unsigned I>
  friend int foo(A const&a) noexcept;
};

template<unsigned I>
int const&at(A const&a) noexcept
{
  static_assert(I<3,"array boundary exceeded");
  return a.x[I];
}

template<unsigned I>
int foo(A const&a) noexcept
{
  int tmp = at<I>(a);
  return tmp*tmp;
}
```

Comment: @DrewDormann: Because of what Xeo wrote in the comments to the question. (btw, +1)

Comment: Does this imply that clang is correct and the other compiler wrong?

Comment: BTW, you only need a *declaration* to be present in the namespace, the definition can still be inside the class namespace (although it will not make any difference, other than for readers of the code)