# clang/g++ difference with friend function

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, friend-function, name-lookup

Why code below well compiled in g++ but get error on clang?

```
#include <iostream>

class Object {};

class Print
{
public:
    template <typename CharT>
    inline friend std::basic_ostream<CharT> & operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT> & out, const Object&)
    {
        return (out << "object");
    }
    static void f( const Object& str )
    {
        std::cout << str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Object() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Proof links: [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afc00647b7baec34) / [clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f60d9ce71a838d1)

When I moved friend function to global namespace, code well compiled for both compilers ([clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3bd205ead6be4b0) / [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf1ef812b90602b0)).

Which implementation in this case is more C++ Standart compatible?

Comment: Clang is probably correct. I think this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15745776/2073257

Comment: @DanielFrey in my case even I remove template i got same error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/765458742bfcea4d

Comment: N.B. GCC 5.0 rejects your example. I think this is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59366 which had a fix committed two days ago

Comment: Xeo's comment on the linked question is the explanation (independent of the template), as also backed up by @TemplateRex's quote from the standard in his answer to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clang is correct here. Friend functions defined inside classes can only be found using argument-dependent-lookup on their arguments, not by ordinary lookup. Because `Print` is not an associated scope to `Object`, the `operator<<` should not be found. Partial quote from the Standard:

**7.3.1.2 Namespace member definitions [namespace.memdef]**

> 3 Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that
>   namespace. If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares
>   a class, function, class template or function template97 the friend is
>   a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. **The friend declaration
>   does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (3.4.1)
>   or qualified lookup (3.4.3).** [ Note: The name of the friend will be
>   visible in its namespace if a matching declaration is provided at
>   namespace scope (either before or after the class definition granting
>   friendship). — end note ] **If a friend function or function template is
>   called, its name may be found by the name lookup that considers
>   functions from namespaces and classes associated with the types of the
>   function arguments (3.4.2).**

As @sehe mentions, the proper way to add an `operator<<` to `Object` is to define it as a global function (using `Object` interface) or as a `friend` function inside itself (using `private` functions from `Object`), not in some auxiliary class. See also Herb Sutter's old GotW column [**"What's in a class?"**](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm)

Answer (score 4):

The iffy thing is to declare an static (friend) operator in *another* class (that is unrelated).

1. You could just create it in the surrounding scope, there's

   - no difference semantically
   - no reason to have it a friend (as `Printer` is not used any way)
   - you can still make it a friend if you needed to

   **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/927f08ebe7c9ab13)**
2. Alternatively, **make** the other class *related*;

   There are many ways to associate namespaces (§3.4.2) with a type for function lookup. For example this hack would be enought to associate the `Print` class namespace with the `Object` type so ADL will still work:

   ```
   template <typename> struct Object_ {};
   typedef Object_<class Print> Object;
   ```

   See this **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f3aac5a030efa86)** as well

Comment: Alternatively, associate the `Print` class namespace with your `Object` type so ADL still works: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f3aac5a030efa86)**

Comment: @0x499602D2 ADL looks up unqualified free functions in all namespaces associated with the argument types. "Associated namespaces" includes those declaring the template argument types.

Comment: So the compiler looks at the associated namespaces of the template arguments? Woah, just learned something new!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69039/discussion-between-sehe-and-0x499602d2).